# How to use angular2 library in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Exists 2 library, for angularJS and for angular2.
I need to use angular2 library for both, from node_modules, but at execution appears errors "exports is no defined", and angularJS does not see the objects from new library...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? If you want to use a component from Angular 2, you can use Web Components

Comment: I need to use angular2 library for both frameworks(angularJs and angular2) .
Library for angularJS should to be removed. This is rewriting from angularJS to angular2.

Comment: I honestly don't understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I use for angularJS wijmo for angularJS and for angular2 wijmo for angular2, together they do not work, when you add at least one module from wijmo(angular2) to somewhere(angular2), then the old wijmo(angularJS) stops working. I need to work wijmo from angular2 with the one from angularJS